# About safe operations involving unique pointers

Tags: c++, c++14, unique-ptr

Consider the following code:

```
#include <memory>

struct Foo { std::unique_ptr<Foo> next; };
void f(Foo &foo) { foo = std::move(*foo.next); }

int main() {
    Foo foo{};
    foo.next = std::make_unique<Foo>();
    foo.next->next = std::make_unique<Foo>();
    f(foo);
}
```

By doing `foo = std::move(*foo.next);`, `foo.next.next` is moved to `foo.next`.
If `foo.next` is invalidated as a first step, the object to which it points could be deleted immediately. This would lead to the deletion of `foo.next.next`, that is the object that I'm trying to move to `foo.next`.
I'm pretty sure I'm missing something in my reasoning, but I can't figure out what's wrong.
Is it a safe operation? Where does the standard reassure me about that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it's all perfectly safe. When you call the `f()` function on `foo`, the move assignment operator of `class Foo` will invoke `std::unique_ptr<Foo>::operator=(std::unique_ptr<Foo>&&)`. Now, the C++14 standard, §20.8.1.2.3, comma 2, says:

> *Effects:* Transfers ownership from `u` to `*this` as if by calling `reset(u.release())` followed by `get_deleter() = std::forward<D>(u.get_deleter())`.

At §20.8.1.2.5, comma 4, we find the behavior of `reset()`:

> *Effects:* assigns `p` to the stored pointer, and then if the old value of the stored pointer, `old_p`, was not equal to `nullptr`, calls `get_deleter()(old_p)`. [ Note: The order of these operations is significant because the call to `get_deleter()` may destroy `*this`. *—end note* ]

So, we can argue that the *stored pointer* will be replaced and **then** the  *old stored pointer* will be deleted, in this order. Thus, everything is fine and well defined.

Furthermore, when you will *enter* into the `reset()` function, the `*foo.next` object will already have been `release()`d, so the pointed object wouldn't be destroyed with it.